# Django filter, if only last value in a query is true

Tags: python, django, django-filter

How to filter all objects of the `ViewModel` if only the last `InfoModel.check_by_client_a` is `True` ?

I have the structure like this:

```py
class InfoModel(model.Models):
    ...
    service = ForeingKey(ServiceModel)
    check_by_client_a = BooleanField()
    check_by_client_b = BooleanField()
    check_date = DateTimeFiled()
    ...

class ServiceModel(model.Models):
    ...

class ViewModel(model.Models):
    ...
    service = ForeingKey(ServiceModel)
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a subquery expression you can annotate on `ViewModel` the value of the last `InfoModel.check_by_client`
after that you can filter by this "new field" if it's true

```py
ViewModel.objects.annotate(last_info_checked=Subquery(
            InfoModel.objects.filter(service=OuterRef('service'))
                             .order_by('-check_date')
                             .values('check_by_client_a')[:1])
                 .filter(last_info_checked=True)
```

see more on: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/

Comment: Thx man, this is exactly what i needed!

Comment: It seems like there's missed `)` after `[:1])`

Answer (score 0):

```
# get last InfoModel
last_info_model = InfoModel.objects.filter(check_by_client_a=True).last()
if last_info_model:
    # filter all ViewModel for the service
    ViewModel.objects.filter(service_id=last_info_model.service_id)
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work, I had tried this way before